# Spring Boot Parallel Processing of files from drop zones locations using multi threading executor services

Tags: spring-boot, multithreading, java-8

I have to change the code to implement parallel processing implementation to scan the below drop zone locations once at a time by implementing multithread processing
Dropzones:SDS-NonK,SDS-K,Eco-Docs,OneToManyPublish,KitMergeOnly

Forex: we have 5 drop zones whenever we have a txt file named as index file placed by business it will go and scan the drop zone location read the txt file and converts it to xml file and write's to output folder, currently it is single thread process.

Comment: //EcoLoaderScheduler.java
private List\<File\> scanDropLocations(String dropLocation) {
FilenameFilter fileNameFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
@Override
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
if(dir.isDirectory()) {
if(validDropZones.contains(name))
{
return true;
}
}
return false;
}
};

I have to change the code to implement parallel processing implementation to scan the below drop zone locations once at a time by implementing multithread processing
dropzone locations: SDS-NonK, SDS-K, Eco-Docs, OneToManyPublish, KitMergeOnly

Comment: File[] dropzones = new File(dropLocation).listFiles(fileNameFilter);
for (File drop : dropzones) {
String[] flagFiles = ecobaseCommUtils.getECOFile(drop);
if (flagFiles.length == 0) {
scanDropLocations(drop.getAbsolutePath());
} else {
for (String f : flagFiles) {
String indexName = f.split("\\.")[0];
File indexFile = new File(ecobaseCommUtils.getValidPath(drop.getAbsolutePath()) + indexName + ecobaseCommUtils.getInputFileExt());
if (indexFile.exists()) {
inputFilesIn.add(indexFile);
} else {
}
}
}
}
return inputFilesIn;
}

Comment: Do not use **comments** for multiline code. Instead, [edit] your **question post** and incorporate all relevant information into it.